# Permit RPM to install file over other RPM's file?

Tags: centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum, rpm

I know, "bad practice". In this case, suppose 2 RPMs which define which things should be installed onto a given server. RPM 1 wants to install `config.json` and RPM 2 wants to install it as well.

*Given that the content of the files in the RPMs are the same*, how can I bypass the conflict given by yum? Note that need to install via `yum`, not `rpm`, because these RPMs have many dependencies which would be pulled from the configured yum repos. These RPMs are for internal use only.

> file /.../config.json from install of <RPM 1> conflicts with file from package <RPM 2>

This use case is that RPM 1 and 2 could be installed on separate servers, or on the same server, depending on the requirements of the deployment. I want to tell yum "it's okay, buddy, go ahead and overwrite the file".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that will actually work is creating a 3rd package, which provides the config.json file and having your two packages "Require:" the config.json-providing package.

Comment: Was hoping to avoid that -- thanks!